# Is HBase 2.X suitable for running on Hadoop 3.X?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hbase

At the HBase [documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop) noted that:

> Hadoop 2.x is faster and includes features, such as short-circuit reads (see Leveraging local data), which will help improve your HBase random read profile. Hadoop 2.x also includes important bug fixes that will improve your overall HBase experience. HBase does not support running with earlier versions of Hadoop. See the table below for requirements specific to different HBase versions.
> **Hadoop 3.x is still in early access releases and has not yet been sufficiently tested by the HBase community for production use cases.**

But right next to this point in the compatibility table says that HBase 2.3.4 is fully functional with Hadoop 3.2.2. So I got confused about whether We can use HBase 2.3.4 in production alongside Hadoop 3.2.2 or not?

Comment: This should work. Cloudera Runtime for example, packages HBase 2.2 with Hadoop 3.1 https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.3/runtime-release-notes/topics/rt-runtime-component-versions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, we have been running HBase 2.2.6 with Hadoop 3.1.1 in production for a few months now without any issues.